# Inverse of $y=1/x$

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions, inverse-function

Can anybody say anything about the inverse function of $y=1/x$ and plot it on a graph and then compare the graphs of the given function and it's inverse? Is $y=1/x$ invertible? If yes then do the graphs of $y=1/x$ and its inverse coincide?

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/functions-inverses can help...

Comment: The function $f$ such that $f(x)=1/x$ is itself.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function section "Graph of the inverse". It says that "This is equivalent to reflecting the graph across the line y = x". The reason that the two graphs are the same is that they are symmetric around the y=x line.

Answer (score 5):

For $x\ne0$, $1/(1/x)=x$, so the function is its own inverse on e.g. $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: A random doubt, is lim 1/x,  x tends to infinty =zero???.

Comment: @ThulashiQwerty $\pm\infty\notin\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

We have a function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
The inverse function, $f^{-1}$ satisfies the equation
$$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}=x \implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$f$ is in fact its own inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equation

$$y=\frac1x$$ for $x$. This immediately gives you

$$x=\frac1y$$ and is valid for $x,y\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

To get an inverse function you need to interchange $x$ and $y$ so here.. the relation  remains unchanged, the equiangular hyperbola remains its own inverse.

For an implicit relation

$$ x^2 + y^2= \sin xy $$

the inverse function also coincides with the first function.

Graph of these functions appear as mirror images with respect to line $x=y$

As an exercise try to find the inverse function

$$ y= \pm \sqrt {(x+1)(3-x)} +1 $$

considering both signs of $\pm$ which also reflect about the line $x=y$ two parts of a circle of radius 2.